# How to add Twitter Pixel on Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do I add a Twitter pixel on next.js in the same way as [facebook pixel](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-facebook-pixel)?

```js
        !function(e,t,n,s,u,a)
        {e.twq ||
          ((s = e.twq =
            function () {
              s.exe ? s.exe.apply(s, arguments) : s.queue.push(arguments);
            }),
          (s.version = "1.1"),
          (s.queue = []),
          (u = t.createElement(n)),
          (u.async = !0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a Twitter Pixel to a Next.js app, you can use the next/script component to load the pixel code asynchronously.

Here's an example of how to do this:

First, go to your Twitter Ads dashboard and create a new conversion tracking pixel. You'll be provided with a snippet of code that includes your unique pixel ID.

In your Next.js app, create a new file called twitter-pixel.js in the public folder. Paste the pixel code into this file, and replace the PIXEL_ID placeholder with your actual pixel ID:

```
!function(e,t,n,s,u,a){e.twq||(s=e.twq=function(){s.exe?s.exe.apply(s,arguments):s.queue.push(arguments);
},s.version='1.1',s.queue= 
[],u=t.createElement(n),u.async=!0,u.src='//static.ads- 
twitter.com/uwt.js',
a=t.getElementsByTagName(n) 
[0],a.parentNode.insertBefore(u,a))} 
(window,document,'script');
// Insert your pixel ID below
twq('init','PIXEL_ID');
twq('track','PageView');
```

In the page where you want to include the pixel, import the next/script component:

```
import Script from 'next/script'
```

Add the Script component to your page, and set the strategy prop to 'lazyOnload' to ensure that the pixel code is loaded asynchronously:

```
export default function MyPage() {
return (
<>
  {/* Your page content goes here */}
  <Script
    src="/twitter-pixel.js"
    strategy="lazyOnload"
  />
</>
)
}
```

Replace MyPage with the name of your actual page component. This will ensure that the pixel code is included on that page.